# Expressing an inverse trig function?

Tags: trigonometry, inverse

I just need a little help with this question:

"Express cos$y$ in terms of cos $y/2$ and hence show that tan$^{-1} sqrt[(1-x)/(1+x)] = 1/2$ cos$^{-1}x$, for $0<x<1$."

I can do the first part, where I express cos$y$ in terms of cos $y/2$, but how do I do the second part of the question?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know then that $\cos(2x) = \cos^2x - \sin^2x$. You also know that $\cos^2x + \sin^2x = 1$. Then dividing by $1$ does not alter anything and so:
$$\cos(2x) = \dfrac{\cos^2x - \sin^2x}{\cos^2x + \sin^2x}$$
Divide numerator and denominator by $\cos^2x$; replace $\dfrac{\sin x}{\cos x}$ by ???

I am sure you can take from here.

Comment: @drhab. Thaks for editing for the old man. Cheers.

Comment: It's an honour to do so!

Comment: @drhab. The honor is mine, young man ! Cheers.

Comment: I realise I've accepted the answer in believing I could complete this, but could you please further explain what I need to do?

I've found the identity of cosx = (1-t^2)/(1+t^2), where t=tan(theta/2), but where do I go from there?

Comment: Refer to http://en.wikipedia.orgwikiInverse_trigonometric_functions. I think you must use the identity Tan[ArcCos[y]] = Sqrt[1-y^2]/y and also use the formula 2 ArcTan[a]=ArcTan[2a/(1-a^2).